Fantasy book in which societies were powered by magic crystals
I am looking for a book I read in elementary school in the early 2000s.
All I can remember is that the societies were powered by magic crystals. I cannot remember the names of characters in the story, but I remember magic being used and there being several books in the series.
I have very little to go on and it's frustrating, because I can picture scenes and moments in my mind.

Can you tell us anything more about the characters, the story, or specific scenes? What you've described so far could potentially match several different books.

Hi Beto and welcome to the SFF Stack Exchange :-) Your question was closed because it's so vague that it matches dozens of books. If you can edit you answer to add details of the scenes and moments you can remember then we'll reopen the question. Any detail, no matter how minor, may help jog someone's memory so include anything and everything you remember.

Could it be The Seventh Tower series? The magic crystals you're remembering might be the Sunstones from the series:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seventh_Tower

The Fall is the first book in Garth Nix's The Seventh Tower series, published in 2000 by Scholastic in partnership with Lucasfilm under the imprint LucasBooks. It tells the story of Tal, a boy who lives in a world with eternal darkness, whose attempt to steal a Sunstone causes him to fall into the unknown world outside of the mysterious castle he grew up in.

